# Is there a way to send json to a remote cfc using XMLHttpRequest()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, coldfusion

I have tried a lot of different options to send json data to a cfc without using jquery, my question is how can that be done using XMLHttpRequest() instead of $.ajax? It sends the request to the CFC but I can't pass any variables to the cfc it keeps saying "FORMDATA" (which is my is not passed in), I have a variable called form data. the only way I was able to get it to work is by using the new formData() object but I need it to work in IE 8 and 9?

```
  <cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="validate" access="remote" >

        <cfargument name="formdata" required="true" type="string"/>

        <!--- <cfif isJSON(arguments.formdata)>
            <cfset values = deserializeJSON(arguments.formdata)>
        </cfif> --->
        <cfdump var="#variables#">
        <cfdump var="#arguments#">

        <cfreturn { STATUS = 200, MESSAGE = "data recieved"}>

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

here is my javascript

```
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open("POST", "validation.cfc?method=validate", true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

          // send the collected data as JSON
         xhr.send(JSON.stringify({formdata:data}));

         xhr.onloadend = function () {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
         };
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The title does not reflect your actual question.

Comment: I apologize I reworded the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send form encoded data for it to be in the `FORM` scope (`arguments` in the case of a remote call to a CFC function).  So change the content type to:

`xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

and change the send() call to:

`xhr.send("formdata=" + JSON.stringify(data));`

and it should come through as a JSON string to the `arguments.formdata` argument.

Comment: thats a good way to do it thank you I actually also did it with angular js

Comment: haha ok, you said no jquery so I assumed you meant no libraries of any kind b/c you were limited to plain ol' js for some reason. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        var params = "method=validate&returnformat=json";
        params += "&formdata=" + json;

        $http({
               method: 'POST', 
               url: 'validation.cfc', 
               data:params, 
               headers: {"Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        }).success(function(data){

            console.log(data);

        })
```